# System.ArgumentException at System.Drawing.ImageFromStream

Tags: c#, sockets, bitmap, memorystream

Ok, so I've seen multiple people with this issue, and I've found to some extent what might be causing the issue, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Basically, I'm trying to send a screenshot from a client to a server via sockets. I take the screenshot on the client application and use this method to convert it to a byte array:

```
// Convert bitmap to byte method
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    byte[] imageData;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
        imageData = stream.ToArray();
        return imageData;
    }
}
```

I then send the length of the byte array and the byte array to the server. The server, after receiving the length, uses this method to get the actual data (this is part of the method since most of it isn't relevant):

```
void dataRecieveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        int rec = sck.EndReceive(ar);

        if (rec <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        recieveBuffer.bufStream.Write(recieveBuffer.buffer, 0, rec);
        recieveBuffer.toRecieve -= rec;

        if (recieveBuffer.toRecieve > 0)
        {
            Array.Clear(recieveBuffer.buffer, 0, recieveBuffer.buffer.Length);
            recieveBuffer.bufStream.Position = 0;
            sck.BeginReceive(recieveBuffer.buffer, 0, recieveBuffer.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, dataRecieveCallback, null);
            return;
        }

        // Convert all recieved data in memory stream to a byte array
        byte[] finalBuffer = recieveBuffer.bufStream.ToArray();
```

I then use the `finalBuffer` to try to get the image, but whenever I do, using this method:

```
        TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
        Bitmap screenShot = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(finalBuffer);
```

I always get a `System.ArgumentException` from `System.Drawing.ImageFromStream`: "parameter is invalid". This code has worked fine for sending strings, but whenever I try to send an image it doesn't work. I'm pretty much sure it's an issue with the socket code because I tried doing this locally by taking a screenshot, converting it to a byte array using the same methods, then using the same method to convert it back, and it worked. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code here?

Here is part of the code for the buffer

```
struct RecBuffer 
{ 
   public const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
   public byte[] buffer;
   public int toRecieve;
   public MemoryStream bufStream;

   public RecBuffer(int toRec) 
   {
      buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
      toRecieve = toRec;
      bufStream = new MemoryStream(toRecieve);
   }
}
```

I used quite a bit of the code from [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCwS7F2uK3Q). At least for the receiving parts.

Comment: did you debug the finalBuffer Byte[] and looked if they match the sources byte[] ? At least the length and the first bytes can be compared. Your receive method looks very strange. What kind of class ist this recieveBuffer ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted more of the code. The code for the recieveBuffer looks like this:    `struct RecBuffer
    {
        public const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        public byte[] buffer;
        public int toRecieve;
        public MemoryStream bufStream;

        public RecBuffer(int toRec)
        {
            buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            toRecieve = toRec;
            bufStream = new MemoryStream(toRecieve);
        }`  I used a lot of this guys code: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCwS7F2uK3Q

Comment: I put this code into your original post. This way it can't be read properly. So did you check the receiving bytes[] already ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm not used to this format.

Comment: Well if you got the code from this guy that is working. Why don't you debug through your code to find the error ? I don't think we can do this here with this short cutout of the whole one.

Comment: The guy's code doesn't appear to fully working sadly, just parts of it. Is his method just bad? It seemed like a smart way to do it to me, but I'm pretty new to socket programming/C#.

Comment: So all the strings I send come through at the same length, but the bitmap doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your `dataRecieveCallback` function.
There you reset the bufStream's position to zero:

```
if (recieveBuffer.toRecieve > 0)
{
  Array.Clear(recieveBuffer.buffer, 0, recieveBuffer.buffer.Length);
  recieveBuffer.bufStream.Position = 0; // <--Here
  sck.BeginReceive(recieveBuffer.buffer, 0, recieveBuffer.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, dataRecieveCallback, null);
  return;
}
```

This means that you overwrite the already received bytes the next time
the system calls your callback function.

So, just remove the line

```
recieveBuffer.bufStream.Position = 0;
```

and your code should work fine.

Comment: Thanks so much! I feel so stupid for not removing that, it was in the example code that I based part of this off, I just didn't give it much thought.

Comment: @user1742916: Your welcome! Please accept my answer by clicking on the hollow check sign below the voting arrows.